# Ripple Effect for pre lollipop

Tags: android, material-design, ripple, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I am developing an app, in which I want to add the ripple effect in my recyclerview. So can anyone tell me the code to do it, and is there a way I can achieve it in pre lollipop too. If not, please suggest me code with my app can show ripple effect in lollipop and upper versions and any simple effect for pre lollipop, to show item has been tapped or clicked.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [this library](https://github.com/rey5137/Material) by this you can add ripple effect on pre-Lolipop version too.

for example

add button in your layout file

```
<com.rey.material.widget.Button
    style="@style/ButtonRippleStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="BUTTON"
    app:rd_enable="true"/>
```

add custom style in your style file

```
<style name="ButtonRippleStyle" parent="Material.Drawable.Ripple.Wave.Light">
    <item name="android:background">@null</item>
    <item name="rd_rippleColor">#20F15A2B</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why are there no ripples on pre-Lollipop?
>
> A lot of what allows RippleDrawable to run smoothly is Android 5.0’s
>   new RenderThread. To optimize for performance on previous versions of
>   Android, we've left RippleDrawable out for now.

http://android-developers.blogspot.com.uy/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html

If you want for pre-lollipop,  you sould use a library like:

https://github.com/balysv/material-ripple

https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect

Others libraries: https://android-arsenal.com/tag/167

For >= 21 API you only need to set in your layout:

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```